# how can i get an array after match query in mongodb aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, match, mongoose-schema

i am learning node js and mongodb , i have a schema of restaurants and a schema of orders with the restaurantId in every object . I am using match query in mongodb aggregation to get some orders where the restaurantId is equal to "restaurantId" , but the problem is that the result is a promise which i want to change to an array of objects to easily manipulate it . So can anyone help me ?
this is the code :

```
 const orders = await Order.aggregate([
  {
    $match:{ restaurantId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(restaurantId)}
  }
])
```

i want use foreach function and other array functions on orders but i can't since the result is a promise ,
thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let me point out that for a query this simple, there isn't even a need to use a aggregation. You can instated go with the plain old `find`.

Having said that, In the specific example you provided, `orders` variable will actually be the array of matched orders due to the presence of `await` in front of the aggregate query. So long as you run that code inside an `async` function, the code should work just fine. Example:

```
const somefunc = async () => {
  const orders = await Order.aggregate([
   {
     $match:{ restaurantId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(restaurantId)}
   }
  ]);

  console.log(orders); //will print an array of orders or [] if no orders are found.
}
```

Another way to run your code without `async`s and `await`s is through the use of `then`. Example:

```
const somefunc = () => {
  Order.aggregate([
   {
     $match:{ restaurantId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(restaurantId)}
   }
  ])
   .then(orders => console.log(orders))
   .catch(e => console.log("error:", e))
}
```

So you are certainly correct in that `Order.aggregate([...])` returns a promise. But you can resolve it by using `await`, which you already do, or `then` as pointed out above.

Comment: Thank you , your answer was very usefull

Comment: @Ghost No problem at all.